# store object with attributes in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function book()
{<br/>
  var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
  <br/>var date=document.getElementById('date').value;
  <br/>var venue=document.getElementById('venue').value;
  <br>var time=document.getElementById('time').value;

 <br/> var reserve=[];
 <br/> 
var input={
           >> name:' ',<br/>
            date:' ',<br/>
            venue:' ',<br/>
            time:' '<br/>
        };


        //load local storage
        reserve = localStorage.getItem("arrayCache");
        reserve = JSON.parse(reserve);
        if(reserve === null || reserve === undefined)//run for the first time
        {

                input={ name:name,
                        date:date,
                        venue:venue,
                        time:venue
                       };
                input=JSON.stringify(input);
                alert(input);

                reserve.push(input);
                localStorage.setItem("arrayCache",JSON.stringify(reserve));
                alert("Data successfully stored.");
         }
         //when array already store data
         else
         {
                for(var x=0; x<reserve.length;x++)
                    {
                            if(date==reserve[x].date && venue==reserve[x].venue && time==reserve[x].time)
                              {
                                    alert("Date and time not available for that venue!");
                                    break;
                              }
                            else
                              {

                                    input={ name:name,
                                            date:date,
                                            venue:venue,
                                            time:venue
                                           };
                                    input=JSON.stringify(input);
                                    alert(input);
                                    reserve.push(input);

                                    localStorage.setItem("arrayCache",JSON.stringify(reserve));
                                    alert("Data successfully stored.");
                                    break;
                              }
                    }
         }
```

}

My problem is that when i tried to store object

```
input={ name:name,
        date:date,
        venue:venue,
        time:venue
       };
```

into array `reserve[]`
using `reserve.push(input)`
it prompt an error saying that "Cannot read property 'push' of null",
But when i tried `alert(input)`, it print out the whole object nicely, i don't know where is the problem.
My expected output would be something like this :

```
reserve(0)={name:name,
            date:date,
            venue:venue,
            time:time}
```

so that later i can compare and check for new user input with `reserve(0).name == name`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You just have to instantiate your array...

Comment: Check that `localStorage.getItem("arrayCache");` actually return a value

Comment: Make sure you add `reserve = [];` before your `reserve.push(input)`. Since you're inside your `if` body, you know that `reserve` is either `null` or `undefined`, thus you need to make it an array before you can `push` to it.

Comment: `reserve = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("arrayCache")) || [];`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to instantiate your `array`.

Your error is throw cause

```
reserve = localStorage.getItem("arrayCache");
reserve = JSON.parse(reserve);
```

don't return an `array`, you've to test before `push` an `item`.

It works after the instantiation

```js
var name ="name";
var date ="10/10/2016";
var type="text";
var reserve;

var input = {
  name:name,
  date:date,
  type:type
};

//Test if array exist and if it's an array
reserve = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && reserve instanceof Array ) ? reserve : []

reserve.push(input);

console.log(reserve)
```

Comment: Note that this is most likely happening inside the body of the `if`. The OP checks to see if `reserve` is `null` or `undefined`, but then attempts to push to it.

Comment: Yes that's why he must instantiate the array when there's this error. I'll edit

Comment: Just wanted to clarify. I'm not so sure the OP understands WHY he must instantiate it.

Comment: i still need to instantiate the array? but i want the input coming from document.getElementById(id).value.

Comment: btw, thanks for the help, im still new to javascript :(

Comment: Yes cause data that you store in reserve are empty so reserve is 'undefined' and/or not an array. So you've to test this before :-)